# Dynamic link pass, but static link fails

Tags: gcc, g++, ld

The following compile/link passes

```
$ g++   --std=c++11 ../gen-cpp/SharedService.cpp ../gen-cpp/shared_types.cpp ../gen-cpp/tutorial_types.cpp  ../gen-cpp/Calculator.cpp ./client.cpp -lthrift
$ ldd ./a.out 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd8830c000)
libthrift-0.9.2.so => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3298d41000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3298a3f000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3298829000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3298467000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f329824b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3299053000)
```

From above, I can see only one library is not found (libthrift).  However, when I try to statically link the library, I get the error message that some libraries are not found. What I find odd is that the libraries mentioned are the ones that are in fact found (per output of ldd above), and no mentioned of libthrift.

```
$ g++ -static   --std=c++11 ../gen-cpp/SharedService.cpp ../gen-cpp/shared_types.cpp ../gen-cpp/tutorial_types.cpp  ../gen-cpp/Calculator.cpp  ./client.cpp -lthrift
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: You apparently don't have static versions of those other libraries installed. You might try using `g++ .... /path/to/libthrift-0.9.2.a` instead of the `-lthrift` method, to statically link only the one library. Either that or fix your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and/or `LD_RUN_PATH` to include the location of the library that `g++` is obviously finding in the link phase...

Comment: Do you know the linker is not complaining that the thrift library is not found.

Comment: Yes. The linker (`ld`) invoked by `g++` is separate from the dynamic linker `ld.so` that is invoked to run a program. If the set of library paths that `ld` is configured to consult is different than those that `ld.so` consults, then you can run into issues like this...